# retrieve photos from my google + account to xcode project

Tags: ios, google-plus

i want to retrieve photos from my Google+ account to project. what should i do?is there any inbuilt library,framework or method in iOS anything? any one have demo?  please it will be helpful for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to this link for detail: [Feed activities performed by user](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list#collection). You will have to mainly use this url, [Retrieve JSON response:  https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/activities/collection](https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/activities/collection), by passing userId of your G+ account and in place of collections, pass public, and rest of the url as it is, perform some HTTP operations, and then parse the JSON response for images to get urls and download them into your project using those urls. This is the way I did in android as it does not support such direct facility for android and ios.

Comment: Thank you Namrata for replay, i found the solution on this problem  by  using this url "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userId" ,
but it returns me only publicly shared and profile photos only. as i want all photos of current user.
i have also tried the way you suggested but it gives me Error like:
 
{"code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."}

where i am already signed in.
do you have any idea?

Comment: FIrst of all, there is a limitation of getting stuff from GooglePlus. You will get only publlcly shared feeds and images in your json response. Secondly, make sure in your google console, Project-->Apis and Authentication --> Credentials --> Public Api Access --> Android Appications part is "Any application allowed" if you have entered sha key and package name there. And in client id proper sha key fingerprint and package name are added.